# building a product of two categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, products

MacLane, as well as probably any other category book, does not hesitate to define a product of two categories as a category consisting of pairs of objects, etc.

Now my question is: what law of nature or logic or anything allows to create such pairs? Pair creation may be an axiom, say, in Set Theory. In category theory there's no such thing; they seem to just fall from heaven, keeping in mind that category theory is not based on sets at all. It looks pretty suspicious to me; but maybe I'm wrong.

Any comments?

P.S. An even curiouser question is about disjoint union of two (non-small) categories.

Comment: A $0$-category is a set. The product of $0$-categories is another $0$-category; this product is the Cartesian product. Is it not natural, then, to define products of $1$-categories, or, in general, $n$-categories?

Comment: Sanath, no, it is not a set, unless you are talking about some interesting kind of set theory, but not ZF or GB.

Comment: Category theory is very much based on sets!  Who told you otherwise?

Comment: There is a notion of product in a bicategory, it is defined similarly to products in categories, but with 2-morphisms implementing higher coherence data.  The bicategory of all categories admits all products and coproducts (and in fact all limits and colimits).  Before Lawvere characterized the category of sets as a well-pointed elementary topos with a natural numbers objects he tried to characterize the category of all categories in a similar way, though as far as I understand his classification did not succeed because he used categories instead of bicategories.

Comment: @EricWofsey not all formulations of category theory require sets.

Comment: Eric Wofsey, category theory is not based on sets. Or else there would be a different category theory for each set theory. Btw, I hope you do not imply set theory is based on set theory.

Comment: @VladPatryshev, you write "it is not a set, unless you are talking about some interesting kind of set theory, but not ZF or GB." In my opinion, the distinction between sets and classes is mainly a terminological thing. "Class" is just a silly (but useful) name for a set in a larger universe. This can be formalized in "ZFC + there exists an inaccessible cardinal", or more realistically, in Tarski-Grothendieck set theory.

Comment: But even if you don't accept any large cardinal axioms, you have to realize that fundamentally, a model $(M,\in^M)$ of ZFC consists of a *set* $M$. The moral is that any universe $M$ of set theory lives in a bigger universe, and $M$ is *small* with respect to that larger universe (i.e. not a proper class.)

Comment: @VladPatryshev: I have no idea what your comment means.  I also don't really know what your question means.  What do you mean when you say "in category theory"?  When most people talk about category theory, category theory isn't something that just stands alone; it's formulated within some foundation for mathematics just like any other part of math.  Pretty much any foundation for mathematics involves an axiomatization of something that can reasonably be called "sets".

Comment: If there's some particular first-order axiomatization of (say) the 2-category of categories independent of any external foundation that you want to work in, then your question becomes meaningful.  But in that case, you're allowed to decide what axioms you want to assume.  If you find that you can't construct products of categories, then your axioms are obviously deficient as a foundation for category theory and you should just add new ones that let you construct products.

Comment: Eric Wofsey, this is a good point. What kind of foundations give category theory the right to form pairs and build product of two categories? And the same applies to sums of categories. Set theory is not a good candidate; and what is?

Comment: Why is set theory not a good candidate?  It's what people use the vast majority of the time they're doing category theory.

Comment: @EricWofsey, or, said more straightforwardly: since we can formulate the notion of a category [internal](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category#internal_category_2) to many categories other than $\mathbf{Set}$, this suggest that large chunks of category theory are not based on set theory.

Comment: @user18921: Sure, you can talk about categories internal to other categories, but then your ambient category is just playing the role of "sets".  The question of whether (as Vlad is asking) you can form products of categories is a question you can't answer without using properties of the ambient category.  In the same way, you shouldn't be able to answer the original question without talking about sets.

Comment: @EricWofsey, I hope you are aware that not every topos has a base Boolean topos. Which means, you can use sets for practical purposes, but you cannot expect anything to be expressible in sets.

Answer (score 7):

My copy of Mac Lane's book is a few thousand miles away from me at the moment, so the following is based on possibly faulty memory, but here goes anyway: Mac Lane works in a set-theoretic foundational system, something like ZFC plus one Grothendieck universe.  So he has no problem with the existence of ordered pairs.

There are people who want to use categories as a foundational system, without any reliance on set theory.  These people need to design their foundational system so as to ensure the existence of products of categories and lots of other things that would ordinarily be provided by a set-based foundation.